# Databind repeater from database with Where statement

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

Hello and thanks for reading this.

Is there some way that I can databind my Repeater to list only the rows that contains somethings that equal a word/number from my QueryString?

Here is an Example of my Nav Url with a QueryString in it : **/Store.aspx?id=12**

Can I bind the repeater to Load all rows where the Column is equal to **12**

```
private void BindItems()
{
    rpStore.DataSource = Menues.GetAll();
    rpStore.DataBind();
}
```

My Menues.cs Class:

```
public static List<Item> GetAll()
{
    using (Scooterfrøen_Entities db = new Scooterfrøen_Entities())
    {
        return db.Item.ToList();
    }
}
```

Btw I'm using Entity FrameWork, so a solution with that is prefence but not needed.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function like this:

```
public static List<Item> GetById(int id)
{
    using (Scooterfrøen_Entities db = new Scooterfrøen_Entities())
    {
        var listOfItemsById = from i in db.Item
                              where i.Id == id 
                              select i;

        return listOfItemsById.ToList();
    }
}
```

When the page loads in **store.aspx** get the id :

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
```